# How to use string.Contains for list of values

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following xmlnode (string) whose value would be of few given type i.e:

```
"Ansi_nulls","Encrypted","Quoted_identifer" etc.
```

I want to test the xmlnode using  `xmlNode.Contains ("xxx","yyy")` ..

What is the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing the full (complete) value of the node, you can do it by reversing the call; check that a list of known values contains your current node value:

```
new[]{"Ansi_nulls","Encrypted","Quoted_identifer", ...}.Contains(xmlNode);
```

Comment: Note that this would only allow full-matches, not equivalent to the OP [`xmlNode.Contains ("xxx","yyy")` which would substrings too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would create an extension method using sehes solution:

```
    public static bool Contains(this string source, params string[] values)
    {
        return values.Any(value => source.Contains(value));
    }
```

That way you can call:

```
        xmlNode.Contains("string", "something else");
```

Answer (score 2):

Contains takes a string to test for.

One way to solve your problem would be to use a simple regular expression

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

if (Regex.IsMatch(nodevalue, "(Ansi_nulls|Encrypted|Quoted_identifer)")...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (new[] {"xxx","yyy"}.Any(n => xmlNode.Contains(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement will work:

```
if (xmlNode.Contains("xxx") && xmlNode.Contains("yyy"))
{
// your work
}
```